# Parse NSStrings out of .m file in XCode

Tags: ruby, perl, xcode, nsstring

I want to rip all of the NSStrings out of a given .m file in my XCode project, so I can more easily localize them.

Any Regex-gurus out there who can help? I am thinking maybe Perl or Ruby would be good places to start?

NSStrings look like this in code:

```
NSString * myStringWhichShouldHaveBeenLocalizedToBeginWith = @"foo";
```

but the part I really want is just **@"foo"**.

Comment: Some sample data would help for those familiar with Perl or Ruby but not XCode.

Answer (score 2):

There's already a built in mechanism for this.  See the [Cocoa string resource docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html).

genstrings is the tool that extracts the strings and writes them into .strings files for translation.  The NSLocalizedString macro (and other related) makes it easy to go get the localized string from the locale specific .strings file.  genstrings doesn't extract all @"" strings, just the ones used with NSLocalizedString, since those are exactly the ones that are supposed to be localized.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with genstrings. Unfortunatly, I have inherited a project with a LOT of NSStrings and would like to be able to rip them out of a file using some relatively simple mechanism. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -wln -e 'next if /^NSString/; print' whatever.m > nonsstring.m
```

That will simply skip lines that start with "NSString" - If you want something fancier, like replacing parts of the lines that have NSStrings, you'll have to give us some more info.

EDIT: Okay, as per the clarification..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my $file = 'whatever.m';

open my $fh, '<', $file;

while (<$fh>) {
    say $+{capture} for /NSString
                          \s* \* \s*
                          [^=]+ \s* = \s*
                        (?<capture>@[^;]+?);
                      /gx;
}
```

Or as a convenient one-liner:

```
perl -wln -E 'print $+{capture} for /NSString\s*\*\s*[^=]+\s*=\s*(?<capture>@[^;]+?);/g' whatever.m
```

EDIT: Since I don't know the form of the data, changed this to handle multiple NSStrings in a single record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 perl -nle 'while (/(@".*?")/g) { print "$1\n";}' <source file>
```

This doesn't correctly handle a string that contains an escaped quote character or a multiline NSString, but it's probably close enough for you.